# Fallout New Vegas - Reset Reputation with the NCR

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am attacked on sight by the NCR. I used console commands to set my reputation to idolized, yet I am still attacked on sight. How can I fix this?

Comment: what are you wearing?

Answer (score 1):

You are wearing Brotherhood power armour. After what happened at Helios One, the two factions have an intense hatred of each other, and the NCR will attack Brotherhood soldiers on sight. Unfortunately, that includes you. Try wearing normal power armour instead (i.e. power armour that does not include "brotherhood" in the name). You can buy most power armour from the vendor in the Hidden Valley Bunker, but make sure to buy the correct set.

Comment: Did OP say they were using brotherhood power armor or is this an assumption?

Comment: It is an assumption. He may have been wearing Caesar's Legion armor, too.

Comment: @Dispenser I assume it's brotherhood since it's less obvious that brotherhood armour turns the ncr against you